# Timing signals in ITU656

Tags: video

I am working on a ITU656 Encoder

Am I correct in saying that in the FF 00 XY timing signal, in which XY is made up up 1FVHPPPP (P are protection bits), that the V bit, which signifies field blanking, is only equal to 1 twice per field: once during the EAV at the end of a field, and once during the SAV for the next field?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question got a minus one, but I got all the info I needed from this website
http://www.spacewire.co.uk/video_standard.html